# another Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Asset.AssetID, AnsMaint.Answer, Convert(datetime, AnsMaint.Answer) as maintasdate
FROM Asset INNER JOIN 
AssetAnswer AnsMaint ON AnsMaint.AssetID = Asset.AssetID INNER JOIN  
AssetField FldMaint ON FldMaint.AssetFieldID = AnsMaint.AssetFieldID 
WHERE FldMaint.FieldText = 'Maint. Agreement Term' 
AND ISDATE(AnsMaint.Answer) = 1 
AND Convert(datetime, AnsMaint.Answer) < DateAdd(d, 145, GetDate())
```

I get the error on the last part of the AND.  If I comment the AND out, it works fine.  My dates in the DB happen to be 10/10/2012 and are valid.  IsDate should weed out anything that is not valid.

In DB the results (when I comment out the last line).  I'm completely stumped.

```
106 10/10/2012  2012-10-10 00:00:00.000
115 10/10/2012  2012-10-10 00:00:00.000
```

MORE interesting tidbits.  If I change the last AND line to

```
AND DateAdd(d, cast(Asset.MaintenanceFreq as int), Convert(datetime, AnsMaint.Answer)) < DateAdd(d, 45, GetDate())
```

it works.  If I take out the 2nd parameter (the cast as int) and replace it with a number or a zero, it gives me the same error.

I'm stumped.  Any help would be so much appreciated!

Oh, AssetMaint.Answer is a varchar field in the DB nothing I can do about that.

Comment: I would say from the SQL dialect, this is SQL Server, but the OP could help by clarifying that.

Comment: "I get the error on the last part of the AND". What's the error message?

Comment: Yes, this is SQLServer sorry.

Comment: error message is: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: A note about `ISDATE()` 'weeding out' non-date values - SQL doesn't really do short-circuit logic like imperative languages; the optimizer is allowed to rearrange things as it sees fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, it sounds like the Answer column contains values for some records which can't be converted to a date, and SQL is choosing an execution plan which evaluates the CONVERT before the ISDATE.

Try using a CASE statement for the conversion instead:

```
WHERE FldMaint.FieldText = 'Maint. Agreement Term' 
AND CASE ISDATE(AnsMaint.Answer) 
   WHEN 1 THEN Convert(datetime, AnsMaint.Answer, 103) 
END < DateAdd(d, 145, GetDate())
```

Comment: Brilliant!  So SQL can "choose" what order to do the execution plan?  That is a bit maddening.

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess , but I'd say it was mm/dd/yyyy versus dd/mm/yyyy.
e.g. 10/10 is okay, but 20/10 or 10/20 might not be.

add the style parameter to the converts e.g.

```
Convert(datetime, AnsMaint.Answer,103)
```

You'll have to look up which one based on what ever date format is in your mis-typed field.